# Count num of rows in PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two questions regarding codes below.

1. I know the second code is correct but not sure if first is also correct both do same thing first one is just easy to write.
2. I want to count the number of rows in database for the selected element `if ($query->num_rows == 1) {` doesn't work so how to `rowcount` for the code below.

First code:

```
 $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username");
 $query->execute(array(':username'=>$un));
```

Second:

```
$result = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username";
$query = $db->prepare( $result ); 
$stmt->bindValue(':username'=>$un);
$query->execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Use `select count(*)` if you just want to count the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to ensure that only one username is selected, you can use LIMIT in your MySQL statement

```
SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or:

````
SELECT DISTINCT(username) from users WHERE username = :username```
````

Even better, when creating the table, you can require that the username is unique:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

Second, to verify that a row was actually retrieved from the dabase, you can use [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username");
$query->execute(array(':username'=>$un));
$rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if($rows[0]) { 
    // Row exists
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the row count. You need just the row itself. So, just *fetch* it, from the first variant, which is ok.

As of the row count, you are supposed to be able to get the proper function name from manual.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 from users WHERE username = ?");
$query->execute(array($un));
if ($query->fetch())
{
    // found
}
```